# remove windows recovery option from grub menu on fedora?

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, grub

I am installing Fedora and Windows dual-boot!

This is my GRUB menu, when I use the Windows recovery option it removes Fedora! So I want to remove this option from GRUB menu.

I tried [how to disable windows recovery environment at start up?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/how-to-disable-windows-recovery-environment-at/59b764e4-3d84-41cc-a7dd-93d83834cbb9?auth=1) but still the same.

[image]

Comment: You can delete Menuentry {"Windows Recovery..."......} and no more appear on grub menu.

Comment: Are you afraid that you accidentally click on it ??

Comment: @Sidahmed yes .. or someone else

Comment: @supriady yes it works :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grub config is stored in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (and `/etc/grub2.cfg`).
You can edit it by typing this in terminal `sudo nano /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Now look for this menuentry and delete it, ending with `}` bracket

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment  (loader)' ... {
... }
```

Then press `Ctrl+O` to save your config and `reboot`

Answer (score 1):

Use [grub customizer](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-grub-customizer-4-0-6-on-fedora-20-fedora-19-opensuse-13-1-and-opensuse-12-3/). It's a *GUI* program that will allow you to configure grub easily. You can use it to hide (remove) the *Windows Recovery Environment*.