# Remove boot options from startup menu

Tags: fedora, boot

I've recently installed Fedora 32 onto what was a Windows machine. This is my first linux machine, and it's really fun.

The thing that's been irritating me is that when I power up the computer, it asks me (momentarily) to select which OS I'd like to boot into. Oddly enough there are 2 or 3 Fedora options and 1 Windows option, with something about it being on /dev/sda1?

Either way, I'd really like it if it only had one option to boot into, and didn't give me the screen to select even though it does choose the correct one after a few seconds. First question: is this possible? And second how can I ensure that there is only one OS to boot into and the rest are now deleted from the machine?

From [remove windows recovery option from grub menu on fedora?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334130/remove-windows-recovery-option-from-grub-menu-on-fedora) it seems I can remove a `menuentry` from `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, but I'm not entirely sure what this does, so some more information here would be helpful.

Comment: `man efibootmgr`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov when I try to actually run `efibootmgr` I get `EFI variables are not supported on this system.`. Haven't had much luck searching for that error message around the web.

Comment: Looks like you're using a system with classic MBR. No idea how to help then.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar myself on how to edit a boot menu using LINUX (though I've edited the boot menu from Windows many times). However, I found an article on Cnet on how to change the boot order on a linux/Windows dual boot computer. Though the article explains how to make windows the default, there should be a way on how to make Linux the default by simply substituting the Windows options for Fedora.

You should be able to find the software in this article in Fedora as easy as you would Ubuntu. The software is called "Startup Manager".

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-boot-order-of-a-dual-boot-linux-pc/